# Iphone sdk Shared instance with class variable

Tags: ios, singleton

I have this problem, I have a class named "GraphGenerator" that other class can call passing a view, to get that view filled with a graph.
This GraphGenerator class is a singleton

```
+ (GraphGenerator *)sharedInstance
    {
        static GraphGenerator *sharedInstance;
        static dispatch_once_t once;
        dispatch_once(&once, ^{
            //allochiamo la sharedInstance
            sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        });
        return sharedInstance;
    }
```

this Class use some synthesized property like _graphType and _graphData while is making a graph.

```
    -(void)generateGraphInView:(CPTGraphHostingView*)hostingView ofType:(NSUInteger)type withData:(NSArray*)data andStyle:(NSUInteger)style{

        _graphData=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:data];
        _graphStyle=style;
        _graphType=type;
```

The problem is that when I start a multiple call at this singleton in a ViewController, the GraphGenerator start to make the graph but not one at time. Seems that the class do all the graph togheter, changing the synthesized property value and making problem..
example, I make this two call at the method

```
[[GraphGenerator sharedInstance]generateGraphInView:graphHost01 ofType:DAILY withData:[_dataDictionary valueForKey:@"day share"] andStyle:BARCHART];

[[GraphGenerator sharedInstance]generateGraphInView:graphHost02 ofType:WEEKLY withData:[_dataDictionary valueForKey:@"week share"] andStyle:BARCHART];
```

the _graphType is setted as DAILY Right afterwards it is setted as WEEKLY, but is setted too fast that the first call is still generating his graph, that, at this point, is generated as weekly instead of daily.

So what can I implement? I thought about mutex or something like this, but i don't know how implement that.
Thank you

Comment: Hi, Why do you need this class to be a singleton?

Comment: Because I dont know if is possible implement a non singleton class for to this work.. I must call this class from all the View Controller in my app, and i thought the best way was make a singleton

Comment: how can I implement a non singleton solution? if I call the graph generator using GraphGenerator * graphGen; [graphGen generateGraphInView......]; I don't get any graph.

Comment: What do you do in generateGraphInView? (beside setting data, type and style)

Comment: it call some method that take the uiview passed as hostingview, and generate the graph in this view. Also graphgenerator is a delegate of coreplot class

Answer (score 1):

Creating a subclass of UIView managing the graph creation for itself will give you a solution without Singleton.

We've used CorePlot previously for a spike and we made it work like this.

This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1) should give you most of the structure.

Comment: Oh, I started to follow that tutorial but then I thought "I can do it alone". Make a sublcasso of uiview Is a nice way to manage the graph creation, you are right.. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

you could put a synchronization in your method

```
-(void)generateGraphInView:(CPTGraphHostingView*)hostingView ofType:(NSUInteger)type withData:(NSArray*)data andStyle:(NSUInteger)style{
    @synchronized(self) {

        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: (but it isn't really a solution, not using a singleton would be best)

Comment: tryed this already, but doesn't work.. still messing up the graph.